# R is giving error when input is expected by the user

Tags: r

So I have the following code:

```
data_load <- function(){
    links_data <- readline(prompt= "Please specify the location of the data for links: ")
    links <- read.csv(links_data, header=T, as.is=T)
    nodes_data <- readline(prompt= "Please specify the location of the data for nodes: ")
    nodes <- read.csv(nodes_data, header=T, as.is=T)
    print("Data Loaded")
    return(list(links=links, nodes=nodes))
}
data=data_load()
links=data$links
nodes=data$nodes
```

When I do `load.all` I don't encounter a problem but when I try to `install and restart` or `clean and build` or when I test/check package. I get the following:

`ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘<package name>’` 
`Exited with status 1.`

Since there is no data available just yet. How can I solve this problem?
I am using RStudio.
Sorry if it is a bad question but I couldn't solve it.